# Not able to copy one HDFS data to another HDFS location using distcp

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, distcp

I am trying to copy one HDFS data to another HDFS location.

I am able to achieve the same using "distcp" command

```
hadoop distcp hdfs://mySrcip:8020/copyDev/* hdfs://myDestip:8020/copyTest
```

But I want to try the same using Java Api.
After a long search found one code and executed . But it didnt copied my src file to destination.

```
public class TouchFile {

/**
 * @param args
 * @throws Exception 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //create configuration object
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://mySrcip:8020/");
    config.set("hadoop.job.ugi", "hdfs");
    /*
     * Distcp
     */
    String sourceNameNode = "hdfs://mySrcip:8020/copyDev";
    String destNameNode = "hdfs://myDestip:8020/copyTest";
    String fileList = "myfile.txt";
    distFileCopy(config,sourceNameNode,destNameNode,fileList);
}
/**
 * Copies files from one cloud to another using Hadoop's distributed copy features. Uses
 * input to build DISTCP configuration settings. 
 *
 * param config Hadoop configuration
 * param sourceNameNode full HDFS path to parent source directory
 * param destNameNode full HDFS path to parent destination directory
 * param fileList Comma separated string of file names in sourceNameNode to be copied to destNameNode
 * returns Elapsed time in milliseconds to copy files
 */
public static long distFileCopy( Configuration config, String sourceNameNode, String destNameNode, String fileList ) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("In dist copy");

    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(fileList,",");
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    while ( tokenizer.hasMoreTokens() ){
        String file = sourceNameNode + "/" + tokenizer.nextToken();
        list.add( file );
    }

    String[] args = new String[list.size() + 1];
    int count = 0;
    for ( String filename : list ){
        args[count++] = filename;
    }

    args[count] = destNameNode;

    System.out.println("args------>"+Arrays.toString(args));
    long st = System.currentTimeMillis();        
    DistCp distCp=new DistCp(config,null);
    distCp.run(args);   
    return System.currentTimeMillis() - st;

}

}
```

Am I doing anything wrong.
Please suggest

Comment: What happens when you execute the above code?

Comment: Code seems correct only. what is the output of line  `System.out.println("args------>"+Arrays.toString(args));` ?

Comment: Nothing happend in destination HDFS

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is solved.

It was Permission issue.

The destination cluster should give permission for user.